# Stop an ajax call if value is false (before any ajax call)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a asp.net mvc3 application.

I have this Jquery function

```
    function CheckSession() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckSession", "Home")',
            success: function (isAvailable) {
                return isAvailable;
            },
            complete: function (owner) {

            },
            error: function (owner) {
                alert('Error Getting session');
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
```

Basically what this session does is call an action from the `HomeController` that action will return true or false.

What I want to do is this,
Before every ajax call in the application I want to first use this function. and if it return `true` we procede with the call, else we dont do anything.

Is there a way to do this **Without having to go through all the code and call it before every ajax call**

I know this can be done by calling it before every ajax and testing the return, but i have tons of ajax calls.

What I'm looking for is an event handler that fires before any ajax call is made

something like this:

```
$(ajax).beforeCall(function (event) {
    if (CheckSession()){
        event.ProceedWithCall;
    }
    else {
         //Stop the call;
         return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do not check sessions with Javascript for anything other than a secondary layer of security for nice presentation.

Comment: @infensus what do you mean? is it unsafe to call a function to check the session from javascript?

Comment: ^ he probably means the point I was trying to get to with my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ajaxSetup` and set the `beforeSend` function like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(){
            return !CheckSession();
      }
});
```

`beforeSend` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. ***Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request.**

`ajaxSetup` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

use the beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) callback:

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this
>   to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as
>   arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend
>   function will cancel the request.

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but this will require me to go through all the ajax calls one by one. Something that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not really. you can set the beforeSend by using $.ajaxSetup() see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd probably make it so that it's your ASP.NET endpoints that call the session-checking logic, and not the client-side Javascript.

Think about it: you fire off an AJAX call that kicks .NET code to check a session, returns a boolean, and fires off another AJAX call if `true`. Why not just fire the **real** AJAX call (i.e. AJAX call 2), and have the ASP.NET endpoint work it out with whatever you're calling with AJAX call 1?

You're going to be saving HTTP request round trips this way, which can have significant gains considering you've got `tons of AJAX calls`.

Just my two cents. Barring that though, I'd go with @gdoron's answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But my problem is this: if the `CheckSession()` returns false, I want to redirect the user to another page. since this is an ajax call, if i redirect from the C# code, the page will get loaded inside a div on my page and not fully redirected. only way to fully redirect the browser to another page is to redirect it from javascript. that's why I need to check it in javascript